# php copy/synchronize/duplicate database with content

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to manage a way of edit content on test_db and when I'm happy with results use a button to update the backup_db, just like you get in blogger per example. When you're happy, you choose the option to publish and your edits go online.

Having no idea on how to, I Googled a while and made this php script.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die("Error!: " . mysql_error()." : ".$connection);

mysql_select_db("test_db") or die (mysql_error()." : ".$connection);

$sql = "mysqldump -h [localhost] -u [user] - p[pass] test_db | mysql -h [localhost] -u [user] -p[pass] backup_db";

system($sql);

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Comment: Please refine your question. You wrote PHP code, which connects to a mySQL instance, and shell code, which executes mysql-tools. Both aren't related. What you do using mysql_* fuctions, doesn't affect the mysqldump tool and vice versa.

Comment: What I want is to clone content from 1 db to another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mysqldump is a command line utility, not a SQL command.

Try this:

```
<?php exec('mysqldump -h [localhost] -u [user] -p[pass] test_db | mysql -h [localhost] -u [user] -p[pass] backup_db');
```

Comment: Just to check, you are substituting your actual connection data, right?  Like `exec('mysqldump -h localhost -u bob -pPASSWORD test | mysql -h localhost -u bob -pPASSWORD test_backup');`  'cause that works for me.  Try doing it manually on the command line until it works and then copy/paste that into your PHP.

Comment: sorry for late reply, it doesn't work, changed my settings of course, but no results, either on localhost or in webserver :-(

Comment: I was using [username] [password] with the brackets... :-( Thanks for help

Comment: no space between the dash and the p switch(SO won't let me change less than 6 words or so :+)

Comment: and depending on privileges aka user rights, using the --single-transaction switch might be necessary (I had to...).